# Tkinter image not being displayed on canvas

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to draw a image on a canvas in my tkinter gui. But when I draw text it is displayed I was wondering why it does not display and how I can fix it?

```
import tkMessageBox, PIL.ImageTk, PIL.Image, socket, queue, ttk
from threading import Thread
from Tkinter import *


class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.pack()

def main(self):
self.bBar = Frame(self, bg="#3A3A3C", bd=0)
self.bBar.place(x=0, y=450, width=700, height=600)

self.can = Canvas(self.bBar, width=700, height=50, highlightthickness=0, bg="red", bd=0)
img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open("Images/uBar.png"))
self.can.pack()
self.can.create_text(100, 10, text="My Text")
self.can.create_image(10,10, image=img, anchor=NW)

if "__Main__":
root = Tk()
root.title("Frozen Cloud")
root.geometry("700x500")
root.config(background="White")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.iconbitmap("Images/Icon.ico")

gui = GUI(root)
#gui.splashSc()
gui.mScreen()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can I see your full script? Or at least with extra details such as `import pil`...also is this within a main function like `def main(self):`...also do you have a `tk loop` anywhere?

Comment: @EcSync Sorry about that I posted the updated code!

Comment: You are using local variable `img` which will be destroyed after exiting the function, and so the image disappeared.  Use `self.img` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I updated the code sorry I forgot to put the class and function. And I tried adding self to the image so it was self.img and it worked like a charm thank you!

Comment: @acw1668 How come I have to reference it as self.img and not img?

Comment: Using `self.img` means it is instance variable and it will not be destroyed like local variable when exiting the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you have used self but not defined within a function, also `root = tk()` should be at the start.

```
root = Tk()
def main(self):

    self.bBar = Frame(self, bg="#3A3A3C", bd=0)
    self.bBar.place(x=0, y=450, width=700, height=600)

    self.can = Canvas(self.bBar, width=700, height=50, highlightthickness=0, bg="red", bd=0)
    img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open("Images/uBar.png"))
    self.can.pack()
    self.can.create_text(100, 10, text="My Text")
    self.can.create_image(10,10, image=img, anchor=NW)

    if "__Main__":

        root.title("Frozen Cloud")
        root.geometry("700x500")
        root.config(background="White")
        root.resizable(0,0)
        root.iconbitmap("iImages/Icon.co")

        gui = GUI(root)
        #gui.splashSc()
        gui.mScreen()

root.mainloop()
```